# Рендер :json без шаблона

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Насколько я знаю, `json` можно рендерить в Rails без шаблонов, выполнив подобный код:

```
render :json => {success:true, head: :no_content}, status: 200
```

Но всё без толку. Получаю одну и ту же ошибку.

```
Started DELETE "/auth/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-28 20:29:27 +0300
Processing by Overrides::SessionsController#destroy as json
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["uid", "demo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "tokens" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["tokens", "{\"xxxxx\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$DvZoMNnonCc7QIPxUGgl2uVgY6ufM4dsdnD7PJxBkdDUJoY9cOXYS\",\"expiry\":1463064626,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$bjFBVZanZhFRnh7D37/X/Or40I4IRSDP/fkzI3Uihucsa8/u.grNm\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-04-28T17:50:26.524+03:00\"},\"a85-6Pqg04JKNheGxUzaXQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$Bmeo9N9CbUeU7S9nnGYLGukzNuBfx6aTlLjR5Lqp7XK0yNldCcVSe\",\"expiry\":1463064559},\"LQquXUPX8XYX2iT9cb5big\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$3IEBKFHUmJH8stSg4erzl.7M/WersmemSgifGm97JAHPSM3QeIhVW\",\"expiry\":1463064626},\"o1ihjtFl80sXmVwRQpylFg\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$FGLKBBipRM8KGUft6.KtQ.1C.4LEr3RV0nX3FsEwtSf3xNgIgBNsK\",\"expiry\":1463064845,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$4rKzo.BwG2eDYU/DUJiN/.D.jbfhlTUO1N1JyPJMtDoCUWZh.ToSa\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-04-28T17:54:05.714+03:00\"},\"default\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$Q3Kpj2K9d.r22BavXNbFSu/swmKsjETvGzwiPe5OUW3OZ0Vx8MaX2\",\"expiry\":1463066712,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$bNfn2noq6iIAelbrOsIZcum7z9aYtghtQzFu6.300zFaYM4N8BtAO\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-04-28T18:25:12.081+03:00\"},\"0Yb2s4qO8whrJftlZdJS3A\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$kGj0h6VTRcb3.36jwvKU8eRcTElFjbY8WVofLOsRbzN8w2wYww0vi\",\"expiry\":1463066405,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$dJso8ZQBJlL5KMPmoB5fROvZr5gIUEbiWP939L/DqGkDkjXSQ2xEC\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-04-28T18:20:05.611+03:00\"},\"3n866Hx7t4GXC8PasANnng\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$uizgREN5xUQDrDutGNF9vu/v.obbj3O.2uF2WWLTeEcUaf51Aiore\",\"expiry\":1463066450,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$rGw/ixMlnkA4Nn1p3qlQiORuMnxBcSZaOVGJaLWNqvG2HAh/uaxry\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-04-28T18:21:03.968+03:00\"},\"xqZiCAeG9qNttkIoH5wC9g\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$XLu75dE44rv.avuesESY3evNLYUP9m.MnxBdFbgZ07ssFbPl1uLLu\",\"expiry\":1463066555,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$v1z4lz/xPceYKo6jjLO7uej3fUTWNQ99Qb/2C8kK7hXPEvaNSoqm.\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-04-28T18:22:35.889+03:00\"},\"dbeTgN6KLQxWKhETjSjKbw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$o122yFjcZW7bZkyigKEUNeldwHBnlqALzqzvl11G3gCm50KWTkkuO\",\"expiry\":1463066693,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$oHIZ87V4RNxBi6DF8pl2ReAXfct3m3E/Iuvbqe.hs8xeEH9.dxdBu\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-04-28T18:24:53.209+03:00\"},\"gvtAHogT3mWo1RBGBP5XwQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$Mrj9itQxCipcnVwR6QzJi.m11QjMMIZ6I/iLcZFuUdntuYA.R0Xva\",\"expiry\":1463066717,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$l2pwhjEEG/qgM28syM8jAuNfqg8y33aMHZh9AvuTiUlNJDfrF2OXu\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-04-28T18:25:17.418+03:00\"}}"], ["updated_at", 2016-04-28 17:29:27 UTC], ["id", 2]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 289ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)



ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template overrides/sessions/destroy, devise_token_auth/sessions/destroy, devise_token_auth/application/destroy, devise/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>["json"], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/dukei/Documents/Projects/YakTalk/app/views"
  * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise_token_auth-0.1.37/app/views"
  * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.0.0.rc2/app/views"
):

app/controllers/overrides/sessions_controller.rb:123:in `render_destroy_success'
app/controllers/overrides/sessions_controller.rb:67:in `destroy'
```

В чём тут может крыться проблема?

---

UPD:

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
module Overrides
  class SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user_by_token, :only => [:destroy]
    after_action :reset_session, :only => [:destroy]
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
      render_new_error
    end

    def create
      # Check
      field = (resource_params.keys.map(&:to_sym) & resource_class.authentication_keys).first

      @resource = nil
      if field
        q_value = resource_params[field]

        if resource_class.case_insensitive_keys.include?(field)
          q_value.downcase!
        end

        q = "#{field.to_s} = ? AND provider='username'"

        if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name.downcase.starts_with? 'mysql'
          q = "BINARY " + q
        end

        @resource = resource_class.where(q, q_value).first
      end

      if @resource and valid_params?(field, q_value) and @resource.valid_password?(resource_params[:password]) and (!@resource.respond_to?(:active_for_authentication?) or @resource.active_for_authentication?)
        # create client id
        @client_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
        @token     = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)

        @resource.tokens[@client_id] = {
            token: BCrypt::Password.create(@token),
            expiry: (Time.now + DeviseTokenAuth.token_lifespan).to_i
        }
        @resource.save

        sign_in(:user, @resource, store: false, bypass: false)

        yield if block_given?

        render_create_success
      elsif @resource and not (!@resource.respond_to?(:active_for_authentication?) or @resource.active_for_authentication?)
        render_create_error_not_confirmed
      else
        render_create_error_bad_credentials
      end
    end

    def destroy
      # remove auth instance variables so that after_action does not run
      user = remove_instance_variable(:@resource) if @resource
      client_id = remove_instance_variable(:@client_id) if @client_id
      remove_instance_variable(:@token) if @token

      if user and client_id and user.tokens[client_id]
        user.tokens.delete(client_id)
        user.save!

        yield if block_given?

        render_destroy_success
      else
        render_destroy_error
      end
    end

    protected

    def valid_params?(key, val)
      resource_params[:password] && key && val
    end

    def get_auth_params
      auth_key = nil
      auth_val = nil

      # iterate thru allowed auth keys, use first found
      resource_class.authentication_keys.each do |k|
        if resource_params[k]
          auth_val = resource_params[k]
          auth_key = k
          break
        end
      end

      # honor devise configuration for case_insensitive_keys
      if resource_class.case_insensitive_keys.include?(auth_key)
        auth_val.downcase!
      end

      return {
          key: auth_key,
          val: auth_val
      }
    end

    def render_new_error
      render json: {
          errors: 'Not supported'
      }, status: 405
    end

    def render_create_success
      render json: {
          data: @resource.token_validation_response
      }
    end

    def render_create_error_not_confirmed
      render json: {
          success: false,
          errors: 'Not confirmed'
      }, status: 401
    end

    def render_create_error_bad_credentials
      render json: {
          errors: 'Wrong username or password'
      }, status: 401
    end

    def render_destroy_success
      render json: {
          success:true
      }, status: 200
    end

    def render_destroy_error
      render json: {
          errors: 'User not found'
      }, status: 404
    end


    private

    def resource_params
      params.permit(*params_for_resource(:sign_in))
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Это баг, конфликт jBuilder и Rails 5.0.0beta3 http://stackoverflow.com/a/36922064/5381547

Comment: Приложите `render_destroy_success`, трейс утверждает, что он в вашем контроллере, в 123 строчке.

Comment: @D-side не стал мелочиться -- выкинул весь контроллер. Удаление `jBuilder` решает вопрос, но может быть вы подскажите, как обойтись без столь крайних мер?

Comment: Да, действительно похоже, что это тот баг. И похоже, что [его починили](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24178).

Comment: @D-side но почему тогда у меня на `Rails 5.0.0beta3` не работает?

Comment: Похоже, что [починили в итоге `jbuilder`](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/commit/26b32cce9cab56713ca24303cb1a71907568738a) и релизов с этим фиксом не было (фикс был 11 дней назад, а последний релиз в феврале).

Comment: @D-side а может есть возможность собрать гем прямо из master. Или это плохая идея?

Comment: [Как обычно](http://bundler.io/git.html), `gem 'jbuilder', git: 'репозиторий', branch: 'master'`... Но в продакшн с таким, наверное, идти не стоит :)

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в config/routes.ru к роуту для delete

```
defaults: { format: :json }
```

или поправьте ваш метод следующим образом

```
def delete
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render json: {
        errors: 'Test 200'
      }, status: 200
    end
  end
end
```